# I want to create a simple calculator in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I am trying to create a simple calculator in jQuery as I created first in javascript but have some confusion in jQuery functions.
First here is my HTML code.

```
<body>
    <h1>Calculator in jQuery</h1>
    <div class="calculator">
    <form name="myform">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="screen" id="screen" name="screen"><br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" name="7" value="7">
                <input type="button" name="8" value="8">
                <input type="button" name="9" value="9">
                <input type="button" name="/" value="/">
                <br>
                <input type="button" name="4" value="4">
                <input type="button" name="5" value="5">
                <input type="button" name="6" value="6">
                <input type="button" name="*" value="*">
                <br>
                <input type="button" name="1" value="1">
                <input type="button" name="2" value="2">
                <input type="button" name="3" value="3">
                <input type="button" name="-" value="-">
                <br>
                <input type="button" name="C" value="C">
                <input type="button" name="CE" value="CE">
                <input type="button" name="0" value="0">
                <input type="button" name="+" value="+">
                <br>
                <input type="button" name="=" value="=">
    </form> 
</body>
```

In jquery tags, I have the basic issues like I created 3 functions but how to link them and how to get output from that functions.
Here are my jQuery functions:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function update(value){
        $("#screen").html(.myform .screen .value) +=value;
    }
        function result(value){
        $("#")  
        }
        function form_reset(value){
        $("#")  
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: First: this `.html(.myform .screen .value) +=value;` is not correctly. Second I would look into binding a click event to your input/buttons and use their value to determine the action they shall perform

Comment: First you have some problems on the html code too... no TR, TD closing tags, BR is strongly not advised to place like this... and I assume your basic knowledge in javascript, and problem solving is lacking of experience. But don't give up! Programing is fun. Try to do some vanillia JS for practising first before JQuery. Or try to follow along some tutorial video like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j59qQ7YWLxw&t=1428s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying the same code as javascript you have to know the basic working of jQuery. And here is the code for the calculator in jQuery.
Style tags

```
<style>
    body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-align: center;
    }
    h1{
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .main{
        margin-left: 470px;
        background-color: #1f1f21;
        width: 30%;

    
    }
     #display{
        width: 93%;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 55px;
        color: black;
        background-color: #fff;
        text-align: right;
        border: 1px solid black;
        outline: none;
    }
    .clear{
        background-color: red;
        color: #fff;
    }
     input{
        background-color: #333;
        color: #fff;
        margin-top: 5px;
        font-size: 25px;
        width: 95px;
        height: 95px;
        border-radius: 40px;
        border-width: 0;
    } 
    .finalresult{
        background-color: #001010;
    }
</style>
```

Now moving towards the jquery tags

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".clc").click(function(){
        $("#display").val($("#display").val() +$(this).val());
      });
      $(".clear").click(function(){
        $("#display").val('');
      }); 
      $(".result").click(function(){
        $("#display").val(eval($("#display").val()));
      });
    });
</script>
```

And here is the basic HTML code for that

```
<h1>Simple Calculator in jQuery</h1><br><br>
    <div class="main">
<!--form tags-->
    <input id="display" type="text" placeholder=""><br>

    <input class="clc" type="button" value="7">
    <input class="clc" type="button" value="8">
    <input class="clc" type="button" value="9">
    <input class="clc" type="button" value="*">
    <br>
    <input class="clc" type="button" value="4">
    <input class="clc" type="button" value="5">
    <input class="clc" type="button" value="6">
    <input class="clc" type="button" value="/">
    <br>
    <input class="clc" type="button" value="1">
    <input class="clc" type="button" value="2">
    <input class="clc" type="button" value="3">
    <input class="clc" type="button" value="-">
    <br>
    <input class="clear" type="button" value="C">
    <input class="clc" type="button" value="0">
    <input class="clc" type="button" value="+">
    <input class="result" type="button" value="=">
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. For example, why do you need that much CSS for the basic working of jQuery?

Comment: CSS is used basically used to create that calculator attractive.
The basic working of jQuery means that you need to read the correct syntax of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the button's click event with `$.on(event, handler)` and get the value of the button with `$.val()`.

You can then use `isNaN()` to check whether or not the clicked button corresponds to a number or a non-number.

<sub>*Note that `$.val()` is primarily used for `<input>, <select>, and <textarea>` elements. For other elements you would typically use `$.html()` or `$.attr()`.</sub>

```js
$(function(){
  $("input[type=button]").on("click", function(){
    let val = $(this).val();
    if(isNaN(val))
    {
      //Handle operators
      console.log("You entered an operator!", val);
    }
    else
    {
      //Handle numbers
      console.log("You entered a number!", val);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <h1>Calculator in jQuery</h1>
    <div class="calculator">
    <form name="myform">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="screen" id="screen" name="screen"><br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" name="7" value="7">
                <input type="button" name="8" value="8">
                <input type="button" name="9" value="9">
                <input type="button" name="/" value="/">
                <br>
                <input type="button" name="4" value="4">
                <input type="button" name="5" value="5">
                <input type="button" name="6" value="6">
                <input type="button" name="*" value="*">
                <br>
                <input type="button" name="1" value="1">
                <input type="button" name="2" value="2">
                <input type="button" name="3" value="3">
                <input type="button" name="-" value="-">
                <br>
                <input type="button" name="C" value="C">
                <input type="button" name="CE" value="CE">
                <input type="button" name="0" value="0">
                <input type="button" name="+" value="+">
                <br>
                <input type="button" name="=" value="=">
    </form> 
</body>
```